# Gremlin for Python returns a list of traversal commands instead of data

Tags: python, aws-lambda, gremlin, amazon-neptune, gremlinpython

I am trying to use an AWS Lambda function w/ Python 3.7 to access my Neptune DB. For a very simple test, I have the following code in my lambda.

```
    g = graph.traversal().withRemote(DriverRemoteConnection('ws://[endpoint]:8182/gremlin','g'))
    g.addV('student').property('name', 'Jeffery').property('GPA', 4.0)

    students = g.V('student').values('name')
    print(numVert)
```

After trying many different traversals the only value I get from the print statement is
`[['V', 'student'], ['values', 'name']]` or some similar list representation of the commands I want to execute instead of the data itself (like Jeffrey).

Am I missing some obvious error? I have tried specifying how I want my result with toList which does not help. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using Gremlin from code you need to always end your query with a terminal step such as `toList`, `next` or `iterate` etc. What you are seeing is just the byte code "to string" form of your query/traversal as the query was not actually executed due to the lack of a terminal step. You also need to use `hasLabel` when you search for the students. The `V()` step takes an optional list of one or more IDs not a label.

```
g.addV('student').property('name', 'Jeffery').property('GPA', 4.0).next()
students = g.V().hasLabel('student').values('name').toList()
print(students)
```

Here is your query run using Gremlin Python

```
>>> g.addV('student').property('name', 'Jeffery').property('GPA', 4.0).next()
v[9eb98696-d979-c492-ab2d-a36a219bac6c]

>>> students = g.V().hasLabel('student').values('name').toList()

>>> print(students)
['Jeffery']
```

Comment: Great, thank you very much for the help. Did you gain all of this from the gremlin docs? I have yet to find a page on gremlin with clear cut descriptions of each function or the fact you need to end any query with a terminal step.

Comment: See if this plus the linked GitHub site helps at all: http://www.kelvinlawrence.net/book/PracticalGremlin.html